# How to write sentiment analysis results from twitter into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, twitter, nlp

I am new to python and NLP , i am working on twitter sentiment analysis.i am able to  print the data along with the polarity and subjectivity also but my goal is to write the data to a csv file which i am not able to do, i am getting IO exception while doing that . Here is my code

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
 import csv

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search('Uk election')
with open("sentiment.txt",'w') as scorefile:
scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scorefile) 
for tweet in public_tweets:
print(tweet.text)
analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
print(analysis.sentiment)
scoreFileWriter.writerow([tweet.text,analysis.sentiment])
```

I am getting exception as ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeet Chatterjee/NLP/sentiment_analysis_twitter.py", line 25, in <module>
    scoreFileWriter.writerow([tweet.text,analysis.sentiment])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

i just want to have 3 columns like polarity , subjectivity and the content in the csv file . Please help

Comment: You have to properly indent your code. All file operations should come inside the `with open(....) as ...` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is really important in python otherwise your blocks are considerered empty.
In your case the `with` block ends immediately and thus the file is closed which is why you get this exception.

The code should probably look like this:

```
public_tweets = api.search('Uk election')
with open("sentiment.txt",'w') as scorefile:
    scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scorefile) 
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        print(analysis.sentiment)
        scoreFileWriter.writerow([tweet.text,analysis.sentiment])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly indent your code.
All file operations should come inside the `with open(....) as ...` block.